# AngularJS : Get each object from array and then make async calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have two tables, Category and Products with a 1-N cardinality.

[image]

What I need to do is get every product that belongs to an specific category.

[image]

This is the html table

```
<tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <td>{{category.id}}</td>
    <td>{{category.name}}</td>
    <td>{{products[category.id]}}</td>
</tr>
```

And this is the controller but I don't know how to merge the *categories* array with the another function in order to get each object from the *categories* array and then make the async call with the $http service

```
app.controller("appController", function($scope. $http, getCategoriesService){

    // Here I get all categories
    $scope.categories = getCategoriesService.query();

    //1. This function receive an object as a parameter and then 
    // make the respective request.
    //2. So what I need to do is send every category from 'categories'
    // array and get all products by category.
    //3. I don't know how to merge this function with the array above
    function(category){
        $http("getProductsByCategory/"+category.id)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.product[category.id];
        })
        .error(function(status){
            console.log(status)
        })
    }
});

app.factory("getCategoriesService", function($resource){
    return $resource("categories", {}, {
        listCategories: {
            method: "GET",
            isArray: true
        }
    })
})
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle it all in your HTML with a second ng-repeat that filters the products by current category, like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="category in categories">
  <td>{{category.id}}</td>
  <td>{{category.name}}</td>
  <td>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter: {categoryId: category.id}">
        <td>{{ product.name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here's a working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/ql5Me7hCRpJ9feVbVBUV?p=preview).

Comment: Nice, please see this example http://plnkr.co/edit/XUMO0Vp9neORCd93v9gE?p=preview I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @wilson - What happened to  product.categoryId (Product / Category Id) in your original question?

Comment: As I'm working with JSON format, the product object has nested the category object not only its id.

Comment: @wilson - In any event, since your dealing with a nested object (category) your filter needs to be this  filter: {category: {id: c.id}}

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your categories, why wouldn't you do something like:

```
categories.forEach(
  category => getProducts(category);
);
```

With `getProducts()` being something like:

```
 function getProducts(category){
        $http("getProductsByCategory/"+category.id)
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.product[category.id];
        })
        .error(function(status){
            console.log(status)
        })
    }
```